# How to change + icon in NatTable TreeGrid to arrow icon?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, nattable

When I am trying TreeGridExample from [*here*](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable)

I get the tree with + expand-collapse icon. How can I change it to arrow icon like |>? I just want to is it customisable too or not.

Comment: Please make an [edit] to include what you've tried.

Comment: I am just trying those examples from tutorial, I just want to know that is it possible using some config attribute from config registry.

Comment: Then you need to be clearer in your question.  At this time your question may be downvoted and/or closed because it would appear you're asking for a tutorial.  Put as much detail in your question as you would expect in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon comes from the TreeImagePainter that is wrapped in a IndentedTreeImagePainter which is configured via cell painter style. To answer the question, yes it is possible.

You might want to have a look at the ThemeConfiguration and the subclasses to see what styles can be adjusted and how.